# How to create a view which contain image and text as like newspaper has?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, image

I want to create a view which contains image and text, like a newspaper has.

For example, in 320 pixel width, a 200 x 100 image. The image is on the left side of the view, and the remaining space on the right side and bottom will contain text.

Comment: Image like this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/WQW60.png

Comment: check this http://robnapier.net/clipping-cgrect-cgpath/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arrange UIImageViews and UITextViews in the way you want them by setting their frames. Then assign images to the imageViews and text to the textViews.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can 3 options:

1. Create a layout with UIIImageViews and UITextView
2. Use HTML and UIWebView
3. NSAttributedString and draw it on a view with CoreText

Comment: In that case you are probably better off using HTML and CSS to format things as you want them and then plug it into a UIWebView as suggested by rckoenes. This has the advantage that it would adapt more gracefully to changing content and rotation.

Comment: Still all options I mentioned can be used, but HTLM and CSS is the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

That's almost certainly laid out in an UIWebView, with the styling on the image set to "float: left" with margin settings that hold the text off from the edge of it but let it wrap around it.

Here's a little tutorial about it: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php

Note that this is about the HTML and CSS content to feed the UIWebView, not anything iOS-ish.